# html Intro page for a website

Tags: html

I have created a html page with the following code in between "head" tags:

```
meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url= contacts.html"
```

Now when the above code is added to a web page, It waits for 5 seconds and moves the contacts.html page. If you press the "back" button on your browser, the browser will take you to the previous page which is the "intro page" or the page that I have entered the above code.

But I need to stop that from happening(returning back to the intro page when the 'back' button on the browser is pressed). Is it possible to do so? If its possible, then how? o_O

Comment: So where are you planning to go after clicking "back"?

Comment: you are going to get more downvote unless your question is clear and understandable.

Comment: please make it clear what you want to ask, so that we can give answer.

Comment: i think @redseptember24 is beginner so we have to help him not have to jus down his moral.

Comment: The question is clear to me, but where's the code? :) He wants to prevent that you can go back in history after you watched the intro or visited the intro page.

Comment: code : (meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url= contacts.html")

Comment: nvm... looks like its a stupid question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to do this, but JavaScript isn't foolproof because someone could turn off their javascript and bypass your mechanism.

Add this inside your  and add `onload="preventHistoryBack()"` to your -tag in your content.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preventHistoryBack() {
        for(var i = 0; i < window.history.length; i++) {
            window.history.back(i) = window.location;
        }
    }
</script>

<body onload="preventHistoryBack()">
```

This will replace the complete history of the browser with your current location. So when the user hits the back button, it will go to the same page as he is now.